# Установка Microsoft Office в линукс через play on linux

Tags: linux, wine

Установил вайн и плей он линукс, скачал ворд, начал установку, спустя какое то время появляется ошибка Error: Invalid name.Чуть дальше Error in POL_Wine. И так уже 5й раз, после каждого раза удаляю вайн и плей он линукс, устанавливаю заново, и все ровно один и тот же исход. В чем загвоздка подскажите пжлста.

Comment: как у тебя офис установится без .Net пакета? Libreoffice лучше юзай

Comment: я бы так и делал, если бы либре все доки с винды открывал.

Comment: А если попробовать офис 2010?

Comment: его как раз и устанавливаю.

Comment: @OlegGoretskyi, там есть пресет с офисом - ты его используешь, или пытаешься сам поставить?

Comment: какой такой пресет?

Comment: в лине свой офис не слабый ...

Comment: @oleg_goretskyi. у вас одна машина с Linux только? Если есть лаптоп с виндой ставте на него оффис и подлючайтесь через RDP (Ramina и компания). Мы так удаленный рабочий стол для всего оффиса подняли у кого Linux.

Comment: @OlegGoretskyi > "я бы так и делал, если бы либре все доки с винды открывал". А можно пример доков, которые он не открывает? Ни разу в жизни таких не видел.

Answer (score 1):

Как вариант: скачиваем из этой сборки настроенный префикс wine 
https://rutracker.org/forum/viewtopic.php?t=5343942

Далее:

```
sudo apt-get install winbind libnss-winbind libpam-winbind
```

Далее, только если требуется(я уже не помню, устанавливал ли я их, но в вики "Ввод компьютера в домен Windows" они указаны):

```
sudo apt-get install krb5-user libpam-krb5
sudo apt-get install samba
```

Запускаем установку и, в последствии, сам офис с помощью

```
WINEPREFIX="/home/user/каталог_с_префиксом/" wine /home/user/path_to_.exe
```

Comment: А зачем устанавливать пакеты для доменной авторизации, если цель - установка Office?

Answer (score 1):

Office 2013 должен тоже без проблем ставится в Wine 2.0
установи через winetricks msxml6, vcrun2010.

для Office 2010 32-битный Wine, и .NET Framework 3.5

Смотри зависимости на официальном сайте вайна, в дополнениям к туториолам по установке
https://appdb.winehq.org/objectManager.php?sClass=version&iId=22248